# PERL: Check if file exists, email a flag to the user that the report didn't exist, zip the files and transfer them

Tags: excel, perl, pdf, zip, putty

Can any one help me creating a zip file out of two files one a excel and one a pdf. Im doing this without the Archive::zip because I can not install it. I am trying to go through the directory and pick up two files an excel and pdf and then zip them and send an error message or alert that says it has been zipped.

```
       sub monthly_report_in {
        ### configure local variables
         $StatusP="false";
         $StatusX="false";
         local $id,$pw,$tpwd_id,$geek_pw,$reportm_date,$file_count,$geg_id,$geg_pw,$month_abbrv;
         local $org1="bfn";
         local $org2="geg";
         local $db_server_name=" ";
         local $home_dir=" ";
         local $archive_dir=" ";
         local $smb_server="";
         local $smb_folder="";
         local $smb_folder="";
         local $reportm_temp="";
         local $input_name2="RegistrationStatsexcel.xls";
         local $zip_input_file="RegistrationByCity*.*";

        ############################################################
        # clean up and create file names                           #
        # gets the date, month, and year.                          #
        #Then creates zipped file named montly.month.year.zip      #
        ############################################################
         get_reportm_date($reportm_temp,$reportm_date);
         get_month_abbrv($month_abbrv);
         get_year($year);
        local $file_folder_name="$db_server_name"."."."$reportm_date"."."monthly";
        local $sftp_dir="";
         local $zipped_file="monthly_statsreport.$month_abbrv"."$year".".zip";

        ##############################################################
        # configure email message content                            #
        # sends user the message that the file has been transferred  #
        #  or an error message that says there were no files         #
        ##############################################################
         local $send_mail="email addy";
        local $good_subject="$zipped_file file transferred to server: $DATE";
        local $good_message="$good_subject";
        local $error_messsage1="Error! No Monthly Reports Found:  $DATE";
        local $error_message1="No monthly reports were found.'\n\n' Contact The Help Desk.'\n\n'script name: $SCRIPT";
         local $smb_subject=" $zipped_file transfered to server ";
        local $smb_message="$zipped_input_file transferred to server $smb_folder\n";
        local $zero_subject = "Monthly Stats files are 0 bytes: $DATE";
         local $zero_message = "Monthly report Stats files are 0 bytes in size.\n\n Please Contact the Help Desk .";

        #########################################################
        #creates new directory and changes to new directory     #
        #get the ID and password for the organization           #
        #########################################################
          mkdir($current_dir);
         chdir($current_dir);
         get_id_and_pw($org1,$id,$pw);

        ##########################################################
        #smb transfer and archive pdf & excel file               #
        ##########################################################
         checkif_fileexists($current_dir,$pdf_ext,$StatusP,$error_message,$good_message);
         checkif_fileexists($current_dir,$xls_ext,$StatusX,$error_message,$good_message);
        print "---$StatusP---\n";
        if (($StatusP =~ "false") && ($StatusX =~ "false")) {
            good_mail($error_message,$error_subject1,$send_mail);
               }
               elseif (($StatusP =~ "zero") && ($StatusX =~ "true")) {
                  good_mail($good_message,$good_subject,$send_mail);
               do_zip_files($current_dir,$zip_input_file);
               get_id_and_pw($org2,$geg_id,$geg_pw,$smb_server,$smb_folder,$input_file);
                 smb_put($current_dir,$geg_id,$geg_pw,$smb_server,$smb_folder,$zip_folder,$zip_input_file);
               do_move($current_dir,$zip_input_file,$archive_dir,$zip_input_file);
                  good_mail($smb_message,$smb_subject,$send_mail);
                  }
                     else {
               ### if pdf file exists, this will transfer the file and notify users
                  if ($StatusP =~ "true") {
                  do_zip_files($org2,$geg_id,$geg_pw,$smb_server,$smb_folder,$input_folder);
                  local $error_subject_pdf="$input_file2 report not found: $DATE";
                  local $error_subject_message1a="monthly report $input_file2 was not found today. 'n\n\'Compressed $input_file has been transferrd to $smb_server $smb_folder.'n\n\' Please Contact
                  The Help  check $SCRIPT";
               good_mail($error_message1a,$error_subject1a,$send_mail);
              }
             elseif ($StatusP =! "true");{
             do_zip_files($current_dir,$pdf_ext,$input_file2);
             get_id_and_pw($org2,$geg_id,$geg_id,$geg_pw);
             smb_put($current_dir,$geg_id,$geg_pw,$smb_server,$smb_folder,$input_file2);
                    do_move($current_dir,$zip_input_file,$archive_dir,$input_file2);
                    local $error_subject2="$input_file1 report not found: $DATE";
                 local $error_message2="Monthly report $input_file1 was not found today. 'n\n\' Please Contact The Help Desk $SCRIPT";
                         good_mail($error_message1,$error_subject1,$send_mail);
                         }
                        }
                    chdir($home_dir);
                        ###
                        }
```

Comment: Your subroutine won't compile. Is that part of a bigger program, or have you written it in isolation? If you just put what you have written through Perl it will give you a list of things that need fixing. Software shouldn't be written in a big chunk like that - you should write maybe six lines of code at a time before testing that it will at least compile. You should use `local` very rarely, and you should indent your code so that it reflects the structureof the algorithm. I don't think anyone can help you better than that before you make some improvements

Comment: this is written in isolation. could you help me. I am in desperate need of understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you need help to install `Archive::Zip`? Or is it a procedural limitation? There are other modules that will help you unpack a zip archive

Comment: If you're modifying existing code then you really should say so. People will understand the problem better, as well as being more forgiving of the quality of code

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but it is way too big for a comment and should help you towards a solution.

All I can do is offer a better-formatted version of your subroutine. I hope you can see how much easier it is to read?

As I said in my comment, `local` is almost never the right thing to use. You should also write very small sections of code and test thoroughly as you write more. If you create a whole subroutine like that then it is pretty much bound to be wrong.

Once more thing, *please* don't just submit what I've written. I have no idea whether any of it is correct, and it is still a very lazy piece of programming. You should start by making sure that your subroutine is even being called, with just

```
sub monthly_report_in {
  print "entered 'monthly_report_in'\n";
}
```

and add functionality incrementally from there.

Here's the reformat. Please treat it with suspicion

```
sub monthly_report_in {

  ### Configure local variables

  $StatusP = 'false';
  $StatusX = 'false';

  my ($id, $pw, $tpwd_id, $geek_pw, $reportm_date, $file_count, $geg_id, $geg_pw, $month_abbrv);
  my ($org1, $org2)  = qw/ bfn geg /;
  my $db_server_name = ' ';
  my $home_dir       = ' ';
  my $archive_dir    = ' ';
  my $smb_server     = '';
  my $smb_folder     = '';
  my $smb_folder     = '';
  my $reportm_temp   = '';
  my $input_name2    = 'RegistrationStatsexcel.xls';
  my $zip_input_file = 'RegistrationByCity*.*';

  ############################################################
  # clean up and create file names                           #
  # gets the date, month, and year.                          #
  # Then creates zipped file named montly.month.year.zip      #
  ############################################################

  get_reportm_date($reportm_temp, $reportm_date);
  get_month_abbrv($month_abbrv);
  get_year($year);

  my $file_folder_name = "${db_server_name}.${reportm_date}.monthly";
  my $sftp_dir         = '';
  my $zipped_file      = "monthly_statsreport.${month_abbrv}${year}.zip";

  ##############################################################
  # configure email message content                            #
  # sends user the message that the file has been transferred  #
  # or an error message that says there were no files         #
  ##############################################################

  my $send_mail        = 'email addy';
  my $good_subject     = "$zipped_file file transferred to server: $DATE";
  my $good_message     = $good_subject;
  my $error_messsage1  = "Error! No Monthly Reports Found: $DATE";
  my $error_message1   = "No monthly reports were found.\n\nContact The Help Desk.\n\nScript name: $SCRIPT";
  my $smb_subject      = "${zipped_file} transfered to server ";
  my $smb_message      = "${zipped_input_file} transferred to server ${smb_folder}\n";
  my $zero_subject     = "Monthly Stats files are 0 bytes: $DATE";
  my $zero_message     = "Monthly report Stats files are 0 bytes in size.\n\nPlease Contact the Help Desk.";

  #########################################################
  # creates new directory and changes to new directory     #
  # get the ID and password for the organization           #
  #########################################################

  mkdir($current_dir);
  chdir($current_dir);
  get_id_and_pw($org1, $id, $pw);

  ##########################################################
  # smb transfer and archive pdf & excel file               #
  ##########################################################

  checkif_fileexists($current_dir, $pdf_ext, $StatusP, $error_message, $good_message);
  checkif_fileexists($current_dir, $xls_ext, $StatusX, $error_message, $good_message);
  print "---${StatusP}---\n";
  if ( $StatusP eq 'false' and $StatusX eq 'false') {
    good_mail($error_message, $error_subject1, $send_mail);
  }
  elsif ($StatusP eq 'zero' and $StatusX eq 'true') {
    good_mail($good_message, $good_subject, $send_mail);
    do_zip_files($current_dir, $zip_input_file);
    get_id_and_pw($org2, $geg_id, $geg_pw, $smb_server, $smb_folder, $input_file);
    smb_put($current_dir, $geg_id, $geg_pw, $smb_server, $smb_folder, $zip_folder, $zip_input_file);
    do_move($current_dir, $zip_input_file, $archive_dir, $zip_input_file);
    good_mail($smb_message, $smb_subject, $send_mail);
  }
  else {
    ### If the PDF file exists, this will transfer the file and notify users
    if ($StatusP eq 'true') {

      do_zip_files($org2, $geg_id, $geg_pw, $smb_server, $smb_folder, $input_folder);

      my $error_subject_pdf       = "$input_file2 report not found: $DATE";
      my $error_subject_message1a = "monthly report ${input_file2} was not found today.n\n\Compressed ${input_file} has been transferred to ${smb_server} ${smb_folder}.n\nPlease Contact
The Help check $SCRIPT";
      good_mail($error_message1a, $error_subject1a, $send_mail);
    }
    elsif ($StatusP ne 'true') {
      do_zip_files($current_dir, $pdf_ext, $input_file2);
      get_id_and_pw($org2, $geg_id, $geg_id, $geg_pw);
      smb_put(
        $current_dir, $geg_id,     $geg_pw,
        $smb_server,  $smb_folder, $input_file2
      );
      do_move($current_dir, $zip_input_file, $archive_dir, $input_file2);
      my $error_subject2 = "${input_file1} report not found: $DATE";
      my $error_message2 = "Monthly report ${input_file1} was not found today.n\nPlease Contact The Help Desk $SCRIPT";
      good_mail($error_message1, $error_subject1, $send_mail);
    }
  }

  chdir $home_dir;
}
```

Comment: my apologies, i'm editing this for someone and I'm not used to it. I'm cleaning up someone elses code.I thought I could help but got confused since I couldn't use Archive::Zip

Comment: If your colleague writes code like that then they need all the help they can get

Comment: Give them plenty of chocolate and strong coffee and get them off the `local` habit

Comment: I could tell this person doesn't need any of that at all. more like some yoga and a hug.

Comment: Hugs and yoga are spritual chocolate and coffee. Give them both. And a massage

Comment: I didn't see the previous posts, but there is a limitation I we can not install Archive::zip or any other module doh! and yes it is previous code. I'm just subbing and assisting -doing a terrible job. I haven't seen perl since 98

Comment: @user3689280: There is nothing in that subroutine that works with zip files. If you need to extract from a zip then you need a module to do it. What are your managers thinking? The only alternative is to shell out to gzip or similar, and that makes your code a thousand times more fragile straight away

Comment: there are lower level modules that make it zip.

Comment: Borodin! What would be a good place to do a refresher on perl? - thanks Bria

Comment: @user3689280: You shouldn't post question in the comments section of another question. Stack Overflow is *primarily* a resource where people can look up problems that other people have had and see hwo it was resolved. It is pretty much impossible to find questions posted in side comments like that so start a new post. You also need to explain what the code is doing that is wrong and show any output if possible. Also explain how `comp_files` is called (what are the four parameters?) and post the code for `get_file_size_2`.